# Must query in Should query clause in Elastic Search Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I have a scenario where inside the should clause in elastic search query I need to have a must clause.

eg I need to filter data in such a way that if data should come only for orders that have dispatch Area ids as   10 only and carrier Ids as 1,2,3 only but should also pull data for all orders having driver id as 1,2,3.

In my current scenario its pulling data for all carrier Ids as 1,2,3 and dispatch area ids 10 and also dispatch areas which are not 10 .i.e if carrier id 1 had dispatch area-id as 9 that data is also coming.

how can I add a must clause in should query.

```
{
      "from": 0,
      "size": 10000,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  [
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "dispatchAreaId": [
                          10
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "carrierId": [
                          1,2,3
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "driverIds": [
                          1,2,3
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below Query

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "dispatchAreaId": [
              10
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "dispatchAreaId": [
                    10
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "carrierId": [
                    1,
                    2,
                    3
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, Richa, will accept your answer, i was also trying with must clause in should,but might be I was missing something in api gateway mapping template.working now

Comment: Happy To Help .